# Java SWT - Is it correct to keep most used Images as static?

Tags: java, image, static, swt

can someone tell me if in SWT (or others, like JavaFX), using images as static without disposing them is bad or acceptable. For instance:

```
public class TemplateImage {

/** ================== STATIC FINAL VALUES ================== */

/** Buttons */

public static final Image IMAGE_BUTTON_EXPAND = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), TemplateImage.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/plus.png"));
public static final Image IMAGE_BUTTON_REDUCE = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), TemplateImage.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/minus.png"));
public static final Image IMAGE_BUTTON_CREATE = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), TemplateImage.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/write.png"));
public static final Image IMAGE_BUTTON_DELETE = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), TemplateImage.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/delete.png"));
public static final Image IMAGE_BUTTON_MODIFY_REFERENCE = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), TemplateImage.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/link.png"));

/** Miscellaneous */

/** Status */
public static final Image IMAGE_ERROR_STATUS = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), TemplateImage.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/error-status.png"));
public static final Image IMAGE_WARNING_STATUS = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), TemplateImage.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/warning-status.png"));
public static final Image IMAGE_UNRESOLVED_CONFLICT_STATUS = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), TemplateImage.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/unresolved-conflict-status.png"));
public static final Image IMAGE_NEW_STATUS = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), TemplateImage.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/new-status.png"));

public static final Image IMAGE_ANGRY_STATUS = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), TemplateImage.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/status-angry.png"));
public static final Image IMAGE_DISAPPOINTED_STATUS = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), TemplateImage.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/status-disappointed.png"));
public static final Image IMAGE_HAPPY_STATUS = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), TemplateImage.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/status-happy.png"));
public static final Image IMAGE_NEUTRAL_STATUS = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), TemplateImage.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/status-neutral.png"));

...
```

Comment: Why would it not be acceptable? It's a matter of preferences to me. I'm more tickled about the final keyword with the initialization at declaration for resources. If your resources are not available, recovery wouldn't be an option...

Comment: I've read many discussions about "you should avoid using static in OOP", I was just wondering and couldn't find a topic about this subject. About the final keyword, it is because I consider that those icons will never change and the images are set in my build.properties. It will always be available like this, no?

Comment: What about if they aren't, whatever the reason? Or as it is said in the answer you validated, initialization is not done after the Display device is created? You'll have no clean way to recover from that IMO. There the keyword final becomes a problem because you will have no way of reinitializing your Images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calls to `Display.getCurrent()` mean that you must be sure that this static initialization is done after the `Display` device is created and that the initialization runs on the user interface thread. You will get an error if either of these is wrong.

Other than that there is no problem with static images.

Answer (score 0):

If what's using those images is expected to be unloadable from memory or part of a long living process, like Eclipse plug-ins, then static is bad. Otherwise, it's fine.